# spark dataframe union dataframe in spark-solr

Tags: apache-spark, solr, apache-spark-sql

I have query many dataframes from solr.
These dataframe would be union a dataframe

```
var sub = sc.textFile("file:/home/zeppelin/query_term.txt")

def qmap(filter: String, options: Map[String, String]): DataFrame = {
    val qm = Map(
        "query" -> filter
    )
    val df = sqlContext.read.format("solr").options(options).options(qm).load
    return df
}

val dfs = sub.map(x => qmap(x,subject_options)).reduce((x,y) => x.unionAll(y))
```

however, there are some exceptions to count action for dfs.

Please give me some methods or thoughts to fix it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
var sub = sc.textFile("file:/home/zeppelin/query_term.txt")
```

with

```
var sub = sc.textFile("file:/home/zeppelin/query_term.txt").collect
```

Comment: you might consider elaborating on your answer a little bit in case future visitors to this question aren't as familiar with ".collect".  Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for contributing.